# ng-model never populated when radio button (generated by ng-repeat) is clicked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an issue with the following use of `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 Box">
    <hr class="inline-block">
    <h5 class="text-uppercase">2. Catégorie de Professionnelle</h5>
    <div class="btn-group col-xs-12 styleGarde" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label ng-repeat="childcareWorkerType in childcareWorkerTypes" class="btn btn-info">
            <input type="radio"
                   name="childcareWorkerType"
                   ng-required="true"
                   ng-model="$parent.advertisement.childcareWorkerType"
                   value="{{childcareWorkerType}}"/>
            {{'DOMAIN_ENUM_CHILDCARE_WORKER_TYPE_' + childcareWorkerType | translate}}
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use `ng-inspector` and I noticed that the `childcareWorkerType` property of advertisement is always missing. In other words the `ng-model` is not populated.

I tried pointing the `ng-model` property to the `$parent` scope to no avail...

Can anyone please help?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve without controller code

Comment: There isn't much in the controller that is related to this field.

Comment: `childcareWorkerTypes` is an array of strings on the `$rootScope`

Comment: Can you create a plunkr / fiddle to let us play a bit with the code? thanks

Comment: Thanks Ulan & Braulio: bear with me whilst I put together a plunker please.

Comment: @balteo I have updated my fiddle to explain how it works and how it doesn't http://jsfiddle.net/ulan/8zvotubq/1/

Comment: @UlanMurzatayev: I can't reproduce the issue in my plunker... Bear with me whilst I explore your fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the model inside some sort of a wrapper, that was created before `ng-repeat` is called. This will make sure that `ng-repeat` does not create the model in its own scope.

**Controller code**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.types = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
}
```

**View code**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <label ng-repeat="type in types" class="btn btn-info">
       <input type="radio"
           ng-required="true"
           name="type"
           ng-model="model.selectedType"
           ng-value="type"/>
        {{type}}
    </label>
    <div>
        Selected value: {{model.selectedType}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ulan/8zvotubq/1/)